# Get detailed Network state i.e. finegrained sate/Detailed state in case of Network info

Tags: android

I want to get access to Detailed state.

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) arg0.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

NetworkInfo mi = cm.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
NetworkInfo.DetailedState d11 = mi.getDetailedState();
```

But i always get only coarse [grained state](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.State.html)

What I want to know is how do I get access to Detailed state